# What is the correct way to cache SKScene?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I use SKScenes for different screens of my main menu. Each of these screens is rather complicated, sporting dozens of elements.
So each time user moves between those screens there is like 1-2 second lag before going next scene or previous scene as I recreate them each time.

Should I just store my scenes in some singleton after they are created so that next calls are faster?
Is it a good thing to do? Won't it be too memory-heavy?

Comment: You have asked some questions that can't be evaluated given what you have provided in terms of info. Much of it comes down to you evaluating your memory situation, right ? You don't even necessarily need a singleton, you could just have a strong reference for them in your `ViewController` that presents the scenes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some optimization tips:

1) Your biggest memory hog is going to be the graphics. To keep this under control, use SKTexture object with a texture atlas. Always use a texture atlas because:

> Texture atlases can improve memory usage and rendering performance. For example, if you have a scene with sprites drawn with different textures, Sprite Kit performs one drawing pass for each texture. However, if all of the textures were loaded from the same texture atlas, then Sprite Kit can render the sprites in a single drawing pass—and use less memory to do so. Whenever you have textures that are always used together, you should store them in an atlas.

2) Create your texture atlases based on levels so you do not use up memory for nothing. In other words, create an atlas for level 1, another one for level 2 and so on. According to the docs:

> For a larger game, you may need to split the textures into levels or themes. Each level or theme’s textures are designed to fit in a specific amount of memory. When the player starts a new level, you preload all of that level’s texture objects. When the player finishes playing the level, the textures not needed for the next level are discarded.

3) You can use a (SKSpriteNode) singleton if you have a lot of the same animations used in different scenes. For example, an enemy present in all levels who has animations for idle, walking, running, jumping, attacking, etc... The same singleton can load all of your texture alases for your animations. You can also use a singleton to store all of your game sounds and thus further reduce load times but keep an eye on memory usage if you have a lot of sounds/music.

4) Setting the `skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;` also gives an optimization boost. According to the documentation:

> The default value is NO, which means that when multiple nodes share the same z position, those nodes are sorted and rendered in a deterministic order. Parents are rendered before their children, and siblings are rendered from eldest to youngest. When this property is set to YES, the position of the nodes in the tree is ignored when determining the rendering order. The rendering order of nodes at the same z position is arbitrary and may change every time a new frame is rendered. When sibling and parent order is ignored, Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance. If you need nodes to be rendered in a specific and deterministic order, you must set the z position of those nodes.

5) If your images do not absolutely require alpha, do not include it in your images.

6) Remove nodes from the parent if you no longer need them. Also make sure you remove any reference to them such as inclusion in any arrays. The rest is taken care of by SpriteKit as stated in the docs:

> An SKTexture object is created and attached to the sprite. This texture object automatically loads the texture data whenever the sprite node is in the scene, is visible, and is necessary for rendering the scene. Later, if the sprite is removed from the scene or is no longer visible, Sprite Kit can delete the texture data if it needs that memory for other purposes. This automatic memory management simplifies but does not eliminate the work you need to do to manage art assets in your game.

In other words, delete a SKTexture object by removing any strong references to it, including:

1. All texture references from SKSpriteNode and SKEffectNode objects in your game
2. Any strong references to the texture in your own code
3. An SKTextureAtlas object that was used to create the texture object